# What's the point (no-pun) of XPointer ranges?

Tags: xml, range, xpointer

XPointer spec talks about ranges that, as far as I understand, mean you can target two nodes in an XML document and get everything in between them or something. Do people really use this? What is it useful for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used this, actually. But when I work with XSLT, I quite often find myself needing a way of expressing a range (i.e., "select all nodes from xpathX to xpathY") and a bit depending on the structure, it is quite hard to do this correct. Like I said, I don't use it, but if I could apply XPointer in my projects, I would use it if this feature was implemented.

You ask what it is useful for. A simple example: consider a log file. You can simply request a range from point X to Y (i.e., a date range), which can be far easier then the classical approach with XPath. I.e., it is easier and clearer to express.